# Rasa to take some keywords in the phrase and return a custom line

Tags: c#, chatbot, rasa

I am starting with Rasa and chatbots, I do not know if chatbot will be a good thing to solve the problem that I want to solve, and this question is more to "Is possible to do it with chatbots?", and if Chatbot is not the tool to make it, what is the apropriate technology to do what I want to do?

Ok, the problem, I need to identify some things in a phrase and with this I want to make a step to do.

Like, I have some keywords - turn on, turn off, coffe machine, lights, computer, car
And I have the phrase : "Turn off the Daniels computer in the end of the day"

I need a return: Action: Turn Off - What: Daniels computer - When: end of the day

Or that other phrase: Turn on the lights on the kitchen when Daniels arrives
and need the return: Action: Turn on -  What: lights of the kitchen - When: Daniels arrives

The question is, I can do something like it with chatbots? Rasa is a good engine to do this? If it is not possible with Rasa or Chat bots, what king of technology you think is the better way to do this?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this would be a good fit for Rasa. You should take a look at the example project at rasa.com and watch the [Masterclass Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlAQWbhwqLA&list=PL75e0qA87dlHQny7z43NduZHPo6qd-cRc). You should also post at forum.rasa.com.